# Find all bounded infinite sequences of positive integers $(a_n)$ with $a_n = (a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})/(\gcd(a_{n-1},a_{n-2}))$ for $n\ge 2$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility

> Find all bounded infinite sequences of positive integers $(a_n)$ with $a_n = (a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})/(\gcd(a_{n-1},a_{n-2}))$ for $n\ge 2$.

I think the only possible sequence is the constant sequence with each term equal to $2$. Let $g_n = \gcd(a_{n},a_{n+1})$. One can show that $(g_n)$ is eventually constant by proving that it is nonincreasing, since it is bounded below by zero and a convergent sequence of integers is eventually constant (the sequence $g_n$ converges by the Monotone Convergence theorem).  If $d$ divides $a_{n+1}$ and $a_{n+2}$, then it divides $g_n a_{n+2} - a_{n+1} = a_n,$ so $g_{n+1} | g_n$, proving the claim.  Clearly one cannot have $g=1$, since then for all $n$ sufficiently large, $a_n = a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ so $(a_n)$ has a strictly increasing, unbounded subsequence. One should also be able to eliminate the case $g\ge 3$. Now I think once one proves $g=2$, one can use backwards induction to prove that the sequence $(a_n)$ must be as claimed, though I'm not sure about the details.

> Here's some additional justification of the third case of the given answer by acreativename:

For the third case, I think they're assuming $A_{n} = 2$ for $n\ge k-2$ (even if not, the proof should still work if you instead assume this). We have that for all $n\ge k-2, A_n = 2.$ So in particular, $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ cannot both be divisible by $4$ for any $n\ge k-2.$ We have $a_{k+1} = \dfrac{a_{k-1}+a_{k}}2.$ So $a_k$ is even. If $a_k\equiv 0\mod 4,$ then $a_{k-1} + a_k\equiv 0\mod 4$ (as $a_{k+1}$ is even) implies $a_{k-1}\equiv 0\mod 4,$ contradicting $\gcd(a_k, a_{k-1}) = 2.$ Hence $a_k\equiv 2\mod 4,$ and so $a_{k-1}\equiv 2\mod 4.$ But from this point on, I don't know why $a_{k-1}=a_{k-2} = 2$ must hold. Once we show that $a_{k-1} = a_{k-2} = 2,$ we can then conclude the result by backwards induction ($a_{k-j-1} =a_{k-j} = 2\Rightarrow  a_{k-j-2}=2$).

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a_n%3D%5Cfrac%7Ba_%7Bn-1%7D%2Ba_%7Bn-2%7D%7D%7B%5Cgcd(a_%7Bn-1%7D%2Ca_%7Bn-2%7D)%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Abounded&p=1), I found the AoPS threads [$a_{n}= \frac {a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}} {gcd(a_{n-1},a_{n-2})}$](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1870414p12685610) and [Sequence of natural numbers with gcd's](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h514377p2889830), with both saying the problem source is the $1999$ Russian Mathematical Olympiad.

Comment: @JohnOmielan do you have some tips for searching using Approach0? A lot of math olympiad or Putnam-like questions are on AoPs and most of the solutions are right, so it would be useful to know an efficient way to search for stuff.

Comment: My only particular tip regarding searching using Approach0 is that, since I found their UI somewhat difficult to work with, I just normally use their "Raw Query" option to type in one or more search phrases, separated by commas, with MathJax text enclosed in dollar signs, like you would use here. For other details about only Approach0, as well as other search options, please see [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265/602049).

Answer (score 2):

$\textbf{Lemma:}$ when $j \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $\text{gcd}(a_{j+1},a_{j+2})$ divides $\text{gcd}(a_{j},a_{j+1})$

$\textbf{Proof:} $ Put $\text{gcd}(a_{j},a_{j+1}) = A_{j}$ and write $a_{j} = A_{j}v_{j}, a_{j+1} = A_{j+1}v_{j+1}$ where $\text{gcd}(v_{j}, v_{j+1}) = 1$. We have $a_{j+2} = v_{j}+v_{j+1}$ and $\text{gcd}(a_{j+1}, a_{j+2}) = \text{gcd}(A_{j}v_{j+1}, v_{j}+v_{j+1}) = \text{gcd}(A_{j}, v_{j}+v_{j+1})$ as $\text{gcd}(v_{j}, v_{j+1}) = 1$.

Thus by the lemma the sequence $A_{j} := \text{gcd}(a_{j},a_{j+1})$ is a non-increasing sequence with $A_{j+1}|A_{j}$.

We now have three cases to consider;

$\bullet$ If $\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} A_{j} = 1$ then there exists an integer $k$ so that $\text{gcd}(a_{k}, a_{k+1}) = 1$ and $a_{k}, a_{k+1} \geq 1$;  whence by the above lemma we will have $a_{n} = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$ for $n \geq k+2$ and therefore will have $a_{n} \rightarrow \infty$.

$\bullet$ If $\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} A_{j} \geq 3$ then $a_{n} \leq \frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{3}$ for some $n \geq k$ and will therefore have $a_{n} \rightarrow 0$ (trivial exercise) which is impossible.

$\bullet$ If $\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} A_{j} = 2$ then we have $a_{n} = \frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{2}$ for some $n \geq k$. The only way $a_{k-2},a_{k-1},...$ are positive integers under this condition is when $a_{k-1}=a_{k-2} = 2$.

Thus such bounded sequences must eventually collapse to $2$. Now note that if $w \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\frac{w+2}{\text{gcd}(w,2)} = 2$ then $w$ is forced to be $2$. Hence we must have $a_{1} = a_{2} = 2$.

Comment: This is a good answer. However, there's a typo in the first line of your proof with $a_{j+1} = A_{\color{red}{j+1}}v_{j+1}$, where the $\color{red}{j+1}$ subscript should be $\color{red}{j}$ instead. Also, with your second & third cases, I believe your "for some $n \ge k$" statement should more accurately be something like "for all $n \ge k$ for some integer $k$" instead.

Comment: Also for the second case, when you say it's a trivial exercise, I think it's because $a_n = (a_{n-1}+ a_{n-2})/3 < (a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})/2 \leq \max\{a_{n-1}, a_{n-2}\}.$ Also, $a_{n+1} < \max\{a_{n-1}, a_{n}\} \leq \max\{a_{n-1}, a_{n-2}\}$. So we get an infinite decreasing subsequence of $(\max\{a_{n-1}, a_n\})$ even though each term is a positive integer, a contradiction.

Comment: For the third case, I think you're assuming $A_{n} = 2$ for $n\ge k-2$ (even if not, the proof should still work if you instead assume this). We have that for all $n\ge k-2, A_n = 2.$ So in particular, $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ cannot both be divisible by $4$ for any $n\ge k-2.$ We have $a_{k+1} = \dfrac{a_{k-1}+a_{k}}2.$ So $a_k$ is even. If $a_k\equiv 0\mod 4,$ then $a_{k-1} + a_k\equiv 0\mod 4$ (as $a_{k+1}$ is even) implies $a_{k-1}\equiv 0\mod 4,$ contradicting $\gcd(a_k, a_{k-1}) = 2.$ Hence $a_k\equiv 2\mod 4,$ and so $a_{k-1}\equiv 2\mod 4.$